# Diminuir tamanho fisico ao mostrar imagem

Tags: php, javascript, html, imagem

Preciso de uma forma de compactar o tamanho de uma imagem a qual recebo de um terceiro, ou seja, eu recebo o link com o caminho de uma imagem e tenho que mostrar ela em meu site.

O principal problema é que essas imagens são muito grandes e preciso carregar um `thumbnail` delas, como são várias imagens para carregar o site fica muito lento.

Obs: não pretendo compactar e baixar as imagens para meu servidor, preciso abri-las direto do caminho que me é enviado.

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: poste alguma tentativa sua para demonstrar interesse, da forma que esta é tipo uma solicitação "Faça por mim"

Comment: Em qual linguagem?

Comment: Php, html, JavaScript, CSS - foundation

Comment: Oi Otto, desculpe não postar uma tentativa, acontece geralmente se utiliza 3 tamanhos de imagem e se utiliza uma uma de acordo com o tamanho de tela, velocidade de banda entre outros... Acontece que só tenho uma imagem de tamanho grande que vem de um terceira (não fica no nosso servidor) e quero carregar ela de forma compactada para carregar um thumb de forma rápida.

Comment: @vitor vc tentou alguma coisa?

Comment: @vitor tente usar essa [pagina](http://www.jpegreducer.com/) ela comprime a partir de link, sugiro vc cria uma função em php...

Comment: Herbert, na verdade atualmente pegamos a imagem nesse outro servidor e mostramos direto redimencionando, não sabemos oque fazer para mostrar de forma responsiva essa imagem. Pesquisamos como mostrar a imagem de forma responsiva e a única coisa que achamos é ter 3 versões da imagem. Porém só temos uma versão da imagem que não está em nosso servidor. Não podemos por exemplo utilizar PICTUREFILL ou ELEMENTO PICTURE. Resumindo, preciso mostrar um thumb de uma imagem que recebo grande de outro servidor de forma responsiva em meu site.

Comment: Você pode diminuir as imagens com a função [imagecopyresized] (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopyresized.php) da extensão GD para processamento de imagens, na documentação existem alguns exemplos que você pode utilizar

Comment: Acho que eu faria usando ImageMagick e um robozinho que fizesse o download do link, reduzisse e armazenaria o resultado diminuído.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que uma solução seria fazer o uso de cache, mas dessa maneira seria criada uma pasta de cache no servidor,
Um pluglin interessante que já usei foi [Gregwar's Image](https://github.com/Gregwar/Image) , com ele é possível redimensionar uma imagem e salvar em uma pasta de cache melhorando muito o carregamento das páginas.

Comment: +1, Eu também uso o Gregwar :)